# After installing cryptography, still getting error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Python version - 3.11.5
cryptography version - 41.0.3 (I think)

trying to create a simple password manager which encrypts passwords

but I get the error in the title:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'`

after running:
`pip3 install cryptography`

The install was successful but I've added the following line of code to let me encrypt the passwords
`from cryptography.fernet import Fernet`

I've tried pip3 uninstall... and then install again but hasn't made a difference

also reinstalled Python, no effect

Comment: try this: `python -m pip install cryptography`

Comment: it is usually to do with which version,  using the `-m` flag often solves:  https://youtu.be/0C-Nssu3XqE